# displaying selected list of values from one list into another onclick in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have list of data displayed in table. As i click any td i display the list of selected values in another table.The Problem is if i select more than one row then in addition to the previous record next selected value should also be displayed but as per my code that do not happen.Should i use checklist? Or changes can be done in the existing one.code is as follows:

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="width:300px;">
<tr ng-repeat="work in jointworkdata">

  <td ng-click="selectedVal(tab,work.jointwork_name)">{{work.jointwork_name}}</td>
  </tr>
```

and display table is:

```
<table   class="table table-hover"><tr>
<td >{{selectedData}}</td></tr>
```

code in controller is:

```
$scope.selectedVal = function(tab,val) {

        if(tab==1)
        {

         $scope.selectedData=val;}
         };
```

The output gives one record at a time and not all selected since fucntion is getting called on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with 2 way binding https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding .

Lets say you have a simple Controller that has the primary data to display and then a variable that collected the ones the user is adding on.

```
app.controller = function($scope) {
   $scope.data = [1,2,3,4];
   $scope.data2 = new Array();

   $scope.add = function(item) {
       $scope.data2.push(item);
   };
};
```

Now in the view its simple as displaying both of them

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data">
  <td ng-click="add(item)">{{ item }}</td>
</tr>
```

...

```
<tr ng-repeat="item2 in data2">
  <td>{{ item2 }}</td>
</tr>
```

Two way binding will take care of automatically rerunning that `ng-repeat` if any new items are added to the data2 array.